# Seeking an English Equivalent for the Concept of "Evil Eye"

Tags: phrase-request, expressions, phrases, idiomatic-language, translation

I'm trying to understand how to express a concept from my culture in English. In my language, we have a term, which roughly translates to casting the evil eye. This term is often used in situations where someone's success, happiness, or good qualities might inadvertently attract jealousy or harm, often through someone's envious glance or comments.

For example, if I compliment someone's achievements, I might worry about "evil eye" - inadvertently causing them harm through my praise due to envy or negative energies.

Could you please help me understand if there is an equivalent phrase or concept in English?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

### Well, there’s always “[Evil Eye](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/evil-eye)”

However, it’s a slightly [exotic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evil_eye#Around_the_world) concept to English speakers. It also encompasses a wide diversity of West Asian, Middle-Eastern, and Eastern European beliefs into a single phrase.

Most English speakers would understand the concept but it’s something that other people believe; sort of like the way a well-known Christian belief like the Eucharist would sound to a Hindu, or, for that matter, to a Christian who doesn’t practice it. The specific nuance that you are looking for that bad luck coming from praise will probably be missed.

### Better is “don’t jinx it”

Now, this is such a common expression that I was sure I could find a simple definition in an online dictionary; but I can’t.

I can find the [Guinness](https://www.adsoftheworld.com/campaigns/don-t-jinx-it) ad campaign from last year. And [this](https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/9890bc0e-96bc-4b8d-9521-23c19d591882) Simpson’s clip - if it’s on the Simpsons it’s an embedded part of the culture.

Anyway, a jinx is a curse and can be a noun or a verb. “Don’t jinx it” is something you might say when some has or is about to call attention to a good outcome - by doing so, they will bring on a jinx that causes the oposite.

Comment: +1 for "Don't Jinx It", as a native British English speaker I believe this best matches the example OP gave. Also applicable in unusually calm situations, such as an IT helpdesk on Friday afternoon when there are no calls. Someone calls attention to it by saying "It's very quiet today, isn't it?". The appropriate response is "Don't jinx it!", because the mere mention that everyone is enjoying a quiet afternoon is enough to cause a major server to crash!

Comment: I also think *jinx* is the way to go.  *Evil eye* in English is very likely to imply malice (either a literal magical curse, or a metaphorical one).  And normally someone has the power to cast the evil eye, rather than it being a symbol of impersonal bad luck affecting the recipient.

Comment: I'm a Brit, and I might superstitiously say 'Don't tempt fate.', or 'Don't speak too soon!' in response to prematurely optimistic predictions or hopes.

Comment: @ThaRobster I believe the word quiet (often bowdlerized as "the q-word") is especially taboo among practitioners of emergency medicine. Don't say that an Emergency Room or Accident & Emergency department at a hospital is q-word.

Comment: @bdsl the q-word is also considered bad luck in event running, specifically safety services (particularly not helped in one of my teams by something absolutely terrible happening seconds after someone said it two nights in a row). I'd wager lots of other groups are highly superstitious about that q-word too!

Comment: I think "jinx" may be the closest idiomatic expression. However, the way I have heard it used is as a casual superstition/supernatural belief, as though the agent of the jinxing is fate or something. I haven't heard it used to describe potential political repercussions due to envy over praise of another.

Comment: The equivalent is just staring, nothing to do with jinxing. The phrase "Evil eyes" means staring or angry look

Comment: @Richie "Evil eyes" and "the Evil Eye" are related, but not the same thing

Answer (score 4):

The concept "evil eye" carries over literally into English. It is fairly common, as shown in [Google's NGRAM](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=evil%20eye%2Cdirty%20look&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), much more frequently used than some synonyms, such as "dirty look, "look daggers" and "the green eyed monster".

BTW, when someone mentions good news, it's not uncommon for the person to say, ["knock on wood,"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knocking_on_wood) to "avert the evil eye." That phrase is also
common in the Western world, from Egypt to England, from Lebanon to Latin America, and there is a common Yiddish expression, "kein eyin hara", which literally translates to, "without the evil eye," used in the same way.

You might also find the [hamsa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamsa) (خمسة or *khamsa*, *chamsa*) interesting in connection with *evil eye*.

Comment: Native speakers might want to be a bit careful with "dirty look" around ESL colleagues. It can umm.. lead to misunderstandings if the meaning is guessed at.

Comment: ‘Evil eye’ gets far more hits on Google NGram because it’s a much more general term in English than the others and encapsulates a number of slightly different concepts from other cultures. ‘green-eyed monster’ is specifically a euphemism for envy or jealousy, ‘look daggers’ is specifically referring to wishing harm on someone, ‘dirty look’ ranges from general disapproval to a near synonym for ‘look daggers’. ‘evil eye’ could match with any of those except possibly for the more mild meanings of ‘dirty look’, but it also might refer to other things as well.

Comment: Yiddish: The usual spelling is "*kein ayin hara*." Leo Rosten's "The Joys of Yiddish" offers alternate transliterations as *kayn aynhoreh, kineahora* and *kine-ahora*. I've overheard a conversation between Jewish women looking at baby photos that included a phrase that sounded like "kinney-horah-pooh-pooh-pooh" as if to blow away the evil eye with the expulsion of breath. Delightful!

Comment: *kein eien*-**horeh**.  Interesting blend of German and Hebrew in the compound noun.

Comment: Afaik "green-eyed monster" refers to jealousy, not the evil eye.

Comment: “Evil eye”, “dirty look”, “looking daggers”, and “green eyed monster” are not synonyms at all!  “Dirty look” (“he gave me a dirty look”) and “looking daggers” (“he was looking daggers at me”) describe a look of anger or contempt, with little or no superstitious connotation.  “The evil eye” (note it takes “the” not “a”) primarily does refer to the superstition — not necessarily seriously believing in it, but at least referencing it (e.g. “she was giving me the evil eye”). “The green-eyed monster” is a personification/metonym of jealousy — not particularly about a way of looking at all.

Comment: @bdsl Yes, but in a number of cultures which have superstitions about the ‘Eviul Eye’, it’s kind of a passive thing resulting from jealousy or envy, so the association does make some sense in certain contexts.

Comment: The idea that someone's jealousy, even though that person takes no action, could cause harm to befall someone is what those words for jealousy, and "evil eye" have in common, No, they're not exact synonyms.

Comment: @TimR: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding you, but *ayin hara* "the evil eye" is entirely from Hebrew. (In Hebrew, *ayin* means "eye (of)", *ha-* means "the", *ra* means "evil".)

Comment: @ruakh: What I was trying to say (but didn't say very clearly at all) is that the anti-curse is sometimes spelled as a single word, a compound, with or without hyphen, and that its first element is German and the rest is Hebrew.  I  found it interesting that for some speakers it was a single word, and that it was a blend of the languages.

Comment: @TimR, yes, you're correct, it's a portmanteau word now, disconnected from it's roots. BTW, the first word could be "keine', German "not, without" or "k'ain", Hebrew "without" ["k'" prefix, "as", and "ain", "not"]. Consider the English "hiccup", which recently was spelled "hiccough", having nothing to do with a "cup", but a "cough", which had the spoken guttural "gh", a while back. Etymology *is* intriguing.

Answer (score 1):

"*Jinx* is the way to go. *Evil eye* in English is very likely to imply malice (either a literal magical curse, or a metaphorical one). And normally someone has the power to cast the evil eye, rather than it being a symbol of impersonal bad luck affecting the recipient."

*The Crystal Cave* (1970) [Mary Stewart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Stewart_(novelist))

> They also pass St. Peter's nunnery, home of his mother, but they don't stop, continuing on instead towards the cave. Merlin finds himself watching for the ring-dove, but the hillside, this time, is quiet. Merlin has Cadal wait by the horses at the entrance to the cave, warning him that what he might think is smoke will only be the bats. **Cadal once again makes the sign against the evil eye, causing Merlin just to laugh.**

https://thebestnotes.com/booknotes/crystal_cave_stewart/Crystal_Cave_Study_Guide20.html

Answer (score 0):

“Evil eye” is a concept that is well known in English speaking countries. Jinx and bad luck are also acceptable substitutes. Curse and spell as well.

Here are some examples of them being used in Western literature; starting with “jinx”:

> “I write a good amount. I've been gathering up a backlog of stuff and maybe I'll do something with it someday, but I don't want to talk about it just yet because that would **jinx** it.” — [Macaulay Culkin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macaulay_Culkin)

Here is a quote about “bad luck”:

> “I think we consider too much the good luck of the early bird and not enough the **bad luck** of the early worm.” — [Franklin D. Roosevelt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franklin_D._Roosevelt)

Here is a quote about “curse”:

> “Ignorance is the **curse** of God; knowledge is the wing wherewith we fly to heaven.” — [William Shakespeare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Shakespeare)

And finally, here is a quote about “spell”:

> “The best artist has that thought alone Which is contained within the marble shell; The sculptor's hand can only break the **spell** To free the figures slumbering in the stone.” — [Michelangelo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michelangelo)